# Sampling rate is very low with ADS1256 and raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to get data samples from a sensor using a [ADS1256 library](http://shorttext.com/6720a276) with a [Raspberry Pi High-Precision AD/DA Expansion Board](https://www.waveshare.com/high-precision-ad-da-board.htm) on my RaspberryPi 2B

Now as mentioned in their code and datasheet it can take around 30,000 samples per second, but when I am running it, it was taking around 15 samples per second. After some modifications in code, it is taking around 470 samples per second.
I need atleast 1000-1500 samples per second.

Here again is the link to the [ADS1256 code](http://shorttext.com/6720a276).

Comment: Can't open your link.

Comment: Can't open your link.

Comment: I added the datasheet links for easier accessability.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use this at a higher rate of speed.  If you are waiting for DRDY pin to go low for on the order of milliseconds it isn't going to work.  I had no luck in modifying the software.  I tried to use this http://abyz.me.uk/lg/lgpio.html#lguSleep but I never could get the interrupt to activate on the change of DRDY.  It seems that the person who wrote the sample program for the ADS1256 could not either.  I looked at the sample program for the mpc3202. http://abyz.me.uk/lg/lgpio.html#lguSleep  He does similar things; He sleeps for .2s between samples.  That won't work for his sample rate.  One problem is that the raspberry pi has no real-time clock.  I tried some unix time routines and got back 0 as a result.